# why does it show "Received a connection from 0.0.0.0, port 0"?

Tags: c++, sockets

Here's my simple server and client.

**server.cc**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <iostream>

struct TcpConnection {
    int client_id;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t  addr_len;

    ~TcpConnection() {
        shutdown(client_id, SHUT_RDWR);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Creates an endpoint for communication
    int server_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (server_id < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(errno);
    }

    // Assigning a name to a socket
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    // address to accept any incoming messages
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(9219);

    int yes = 1;
    setsockopt(server_id, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));

    if (bind(server_id, (struct sockaddr *)(&addr), sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(errno);
    }

    if (listen(server_id, 5) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(errno);
    }

    while (1) {
        // Accept a connection on a socket
        TcpConnection * conn = new TcpConnection;
        conn->client_id = accept(server_id, 
                (struct sockaddr *)(&conn->client_addr), &(conn->addr_len));

        if (conn->client_id < 0) {
                perror("accept");
                exit(errno);
        } else {
            char ip[16];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(conn->client_addr.sin_addr), ip, 16);
            std::cout << " Received a connection from " << ip << ", port " << conn->client_addr.sin_port << std::endl;

        }

        delete conn;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**client.cc**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <iostream>

std::string get_ip_addr(struct addrinfo* host)
{
    struct sockaddr_in* addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)host->ai_addr;
    char ip[16];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr->sin_addr, ip, 16);
    return std::string(ip);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cout << "Usage: "<< argv[0] << " <server name> <port>\n";
        exit(errno);
    }

    // Create an endpoint for communication
    int client_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    // Get the information of server to be connected
    struct addrinfo * server_ai;

    int rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], 0, &server_ai);
    if ( rv < 0 ) {
        std::cout << gai_strerror(rv) << std::endl;
        exit(errno);
    }

    std::cout << "Connecting to " << argv[1] << 
        "|" << get_ip_addr(server_ai) << "|:" << argv[2] << "... ";
    std::cout.flush();

    // Connect to server
    if ( connect(client_id, server_ai->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("connect");
        exit(errno);
    }

    std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;

    freeaddrinfo(server_ai);
}
```

After lauching the server program, I fire up a client to connect to
this server. The server outputs:

```
Received a connection from 0.0.0.0, port 0
```

So confusing! And then I fire up a client again, the server outputs:

```
Received a connection from 127.0.0.1, port 15566
```

This time I get the expected result. So how to explain the first output?

Comment: This question has been answerd multiple times here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not initialize `conn->addr_len` before calling `accept`. As your struct `TcpConnection` contains a destructor, I suppose its members are set to 0 at initialization.

The third parameter of `accept` is an in/out parameter : according to the man page: *the addrlen argument is a
     value-result argument; it should initially contain the amount of space
     pointed to by addr; on return it will contain the actual length (in
     bytes) of the address returned*.

If it is initialized to 0, it means that you reserved no memory and nothing is written to `conn->client_addr`. You should use a constructor to initialize it explicitely:

```
TcpConnection(): client_id(0) {
    addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to give you an upvote but I can't.

Comment: @wintr: You are welcome... You could just accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `TcpConnection::addr_len`, so its value will be random, when it shouldn't be. If its value is less than the length of `sockaddr_in`, you won't get all the information.

In your case, `addr_len` is set to 0 at first allocation by `new` so `accept()` will not fill the `sockaddr_in`. The call will set `addr_len`, and the next `new` inherit this correct value by chance (because you `delete`, remove `delete` and this won't work at all), so the next `accept()` will fill the address as expected. This is totally undefined behavior, it's just an explanation of what actually happens.